# Android Live Wallpapers with OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

Has anyone managed to get OpenGL ES 2.0 working in a live wallpaper?  I have a class that uses OpenGL ES 2.0 and runs fine as a Renderer for a GLSurfaceView.  However, I want it to function as a live wallpaper.  I found Robert Green's GLWallpaperService, but that is based on an older version of GLSurfaceView and does not support setEGLContextClientVersion, which is needed to run OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: I've found an answer to my own question at https://github.com/ghisguth/blurred-lines-live/blob/master/src/cxa/lineswallpaper/Wallpaper.java

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've been looking for the same :)

Comment: @MJP: Nice! Plz answer your own question with the link.

Comment: Can you please post your solution as an answer below so we can get this off the Unanswered list?  Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've managed to get an opengl-based LWP working by extending GLSurfaceView and then wrapping that in a wallpaper service. I haven't specifically tested if opengl es 2.0 works with this method, but I see no reason it wouldn't.

You can find the LWP specific files at https://github.com/JesusFreke/Penroser/tree/master/src/org/jf/GLWallpaper. They should be generic and usable as-is in other projects. For an example of how to use these classes, see https://github.com/JesusFreke/Penroser/blob/master/src/org/jf/Penroser/PenroserLiveWallpaper.java

Comment: After reading GLSurfaceView source for awhile I ended up with somewhat similar implementation/idea for getting OpenGL support for WallpaperService. But the reason for commenting your answer is that I think you're losing GLThread in your GLWallpaper implementation. It's killed only once GLSurfaceView.onDetachedFromWindow() gets called (or you can call it manually in this case), onSurfaceDestroyed() puts it only in waiting state.

Comment: @harism - how did you implement it differently?
I've worked with JesusFreke's wallpaper service for a while, and it's worked very well. The only issue is when apply the wallpaper from preview mode, where GLThread sometimes throws an exception, but I can't quite figure out how to solve it.

Comment: @Daniel Schuler Only difference is that I implemented an ``onDestroy()`` method to GLSurfaceView which is simply written as ``void onDestroy() { super.onDetachedFromWindow() }``. Calling this will kill the underlying GL thread, otherwise it is being left in idle state in the background. Can't tell if it has anything with the problem you're facing though.

Answer (score 1):

The code at [this blog post](http://www.learnopengles.com/how-to-use-opengl-es-2-in-an-android-live-wallpaper/) adapts Robert Green's GLWallpaperService to work with OpenGL ES 2.0. You may have some success using it, however it would probably be simpler for you to use JesusFreke's implementation.

If you are successful in improving GLWallpaperService please [submit your changes back to the project](https://github.com/GLWallpaperService/GLWallpaperService) so that we can all benefit.