# How to convert an Open GL ES 2.0 application to a Live Wallpaper?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

I have a class which implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer and uses Open GL ES 2.0, and works perfectly as a standard application.

However I'd like to expand this so that its a live wallpaper. Naturyally I've got a service class which exteds WallPaperservice, and in turn a engine class which extends WallpaperService.Engine.

In the normal version of the code I can just do

```
mGLSView = new GLSurfaceView(this); // in the engine this becomes 'new GLSurfaceView(getBaseContext());'
mGLSView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
mGLSView.setRenderer(new myRenderer());
setContentView(mGLSView);
```

However in the 'Engine' you cannot call setContentView. Presumably I need to pass the surface into the GLSurfaceView somehow, but I really cant see how. Every example or tutorial that I've found uses OpenGL 1, and because I'm quite new to this I cant quite figure out how to adapt them for 2.0.

So does anyone know of a simple example of a live wallpaper using OpenGL ES 2.0? Or a good pointer on where to readup?

Thanks,

Comment: This looks promising: http://www.rbgrn.net/content/354-glsurfaceview-adapted-3d-live-wallpapers

Comment: I've been staring at that page for some time, still am infact, trouble is its for Open GL 1, hence the question.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure if the difference in version would be a problem. Not sure then, I've never had the patience to do a live wallpaper in OpenGL myself.

Comment: Actually the GL1 imports are probably for the interfaces. Think there are some language issues from a older version of something, but maybe, just maybe it will work!

Comment: Ok, definatly an issue there. The code is _replacing_ GLSurfaceView, so doesn't (seem) to have an equivalent of 'setEGLContextClientVersion' which you need to enable GL2. The code has its own 'context chooser', so maybe its possible, but I seem to be wading quite deep into the system...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Live Wallpapers with OpenGL ES 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998533/android-live-wallpapers-with-opengl-es-2-0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, got it! If you use the source from http://www.rbgrn.net/content/354-glsurfaceview-adapted-3d-live-wallpapers (And thank you *very* much to Robert Green for this!!)

For whatever reason I had to fix a few syntax errors, I suspect this is from having a newer version of Eclipse or whatever since the original was written.

To enable OpenGL ES 2.0 though, you need to make two changes. In the constructor of ComponentSizeChooser add

```
EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, 4,
```

To the super call. Also in createContext in DefaultContextFactory replace the null with

```
new int[] { 0x3098, 2, EGL10.EGL_NONE }
```

And that should have you enabled for GL ES 2.0.

Also, additionally, on his webpage, he has 'setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);' I suspect most will want this to be 'setRenderMode(RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);'

Full code is available [Here](http://pastebin.com/SCyDLy3c).